# Parameter substitution inside indirect expansion

Tags: bash, command-substitution

I want to achieve the parameter substitution inside indirect expansion, but I cannot achieve it with a single command.
I get a "bad substitution" error. Let me know if there's a clever way of solving this.

So I have to use the extra command to resolve the first variable value, then refer to it inside indirect expansion.

How can I do this in a single command without the extra command resolving the first variable value?

```bash
$ export first="hello"
$ export second_hello="finally"
```

```bash
$ echo ${second_${first}}
bash: ${second_${first}}: bad substitution
```

```bash
$ echo ${!second_${first}}
bash: ${!second_${first}}: bad substitution
```

```bash
$ temp=second_${first}
$ echo ${!temp}
finally
```

I want to avoid the additional `temp` variable to get the string `finally`.

Answer (score 7):

In `bash`, you'll need an intermediary variable:

```
first=hello
second_hello=finally
intermediary=second_$first
printf '%s\n' "${!intermediary}"
```

Though you can always do it the standard way using `eval`:

```
eval 'printf "%s\n" "${second_'"$first"'}"'
```

Where we pass `printf "%s\n" "${second_hello}"` to `eval` and `eval` in turn, interprets it as shell  code which invokes `printf` with `%s\n` and `finally` as separate arguments. Note the quotes in both the outer and inner code to prevent split+glob.

In zsh where the equivalent of `bash`'s `${!var}`, is `${(P)var}`, you can do without an intermediary variable by applying the `P` parameter expansion flag to a `${:-text}` expansion:

```
first=hello
second_hello=finally
printf '%s\n' ${(P)${:-second_$first}}
```

Or using the `e` parameter expansion flag:

```
printf '%s\n' ${(e):-\$second_$first}
```

Note that all those approaches are equally safe if `$first` is guaranteed to contain only characters that are valid in a variable name and equally unsafe (introducing arbitrary command execution vulnerabilities) if not, so you may need to sanitise the value of `$first` if it's provided externally to your script.

Here, you may want to consider using associative arrays instead:

```
typeset -A second
second[hello]=finally
first=hello
printf '%s\n' "${second[$first]}"
```

Though beware you can't `export` an associative array variable as environment variables are only string/scalar. But it doesn't sound like you'd want any of those variables to be exported. You only want to export variables which you expect commands you execute to "import", like you export `MANPATH` for the `man` command to import it to know where to look for man pages.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this without use of the intermediary variable.

```
[cloudshell-user@ip-10-0-25-104 ~]$ first=hello
[cloudshell-user@ip-10-0-25-104 ~]$ second_hello=finally
[cloudshell-user@ip-10-0-25-104 ~]$ eval echo \$second_$first
finally
```

Comment: maybe, but if `hello` contains e.g. a command substitution, the `eval` will evaluate it and execute the command inside, while the indirect expansion with the value passed through a temporary variable will just give an error. Also if you ever want to assign to a variable referenced like that, something like `eval second_$first=...` would need extra quoting on the right hand side too. Use a nameref or an associative array instead.